# How do I suppress the row count for tables added (AUTO_INCREMENT=N) to mysqldump output?

Tags: mysql

I use the following command to output the schema for a MySQL db:

```
mysqldump --no-data --skip-add-drop-table
```

I will do this for two databases I want to compare, and then diff the two output files.  This is my crude way of tracking database changes between environments.

However, a minor inconvenience to me is that the row count for each table is included as part of the table definition, as the AUTO_INCREMENT value, like so:

```
ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=844 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I would think that the '--no-data' flag would suppress any information about the table that references the data, including number of rows.

How do I suppress AUTO_INCREMENT=N in this output?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Check out this [`ticket`](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=20786) on this problem. It was closed as "Won't Fix"

You could do this, alternatively:

```
mysqldump --no-data --skip-add-drop-table my_database | sed 's/AUTO_INCREMENT=[0-9]*\b//' > database.dump
```

Comment: Thanks, I wish there was some way to mark this "great answer" because it truly is, considering the reference to the actual bug report etc.  Bravo and thank you!

Comment: The `sed` part didn't work directly for my unix set-up (FreeBSD bash). But the following `sed` part worked for me: `sed "s/AUTO_INCREMENT=[0-9]*//"` ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
mysqldump --no-data --skip-add-drop-table | grep -v AUTO_INCREMENT
```

?

Comment: Well, AUTO_INCREMENT is on the same line as ENGINE and CHARSET, any differences in which I *would* want to see... so, I don't want to omit the entire line.  Thank you though!

Answer (score 1):

After much research and tweaking I found that on Windows (with Powershell available) you can do...

`mysqldump -h SERVER -u USERNAME --password=PASSWORD -d DATABASE -C | powershell -Command "$input | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace \" AUTO_INCREMENT=\S+\", \"\" }"`

Just add `> output.txt` to the end to save it to a file instead of printing it to screen.

Answer (score 0):

(**Edit** the accepted answer is of course the correct way. Nobody in their right minds makes a column with the default value "AUTO_INCREMENT=123")

Struggling with the same question, and reading the referenced ticket warning about sed'ing a solution, I gave the `--xml` output form a whirl, and I came up with a working solution without the pitfalls (e.g. someone creating a column with a default value "AUTO_INCREMENT=123" —far fetched, I know, but still...):

```
mysqldump \
  --xml \
  --compact \
  --no-data \
  mydb |
xmlstarlet ed -d '
  //key/@Cardinality |
  //options/@Rows |
  //options/@Avg_row_length |
  //options/@Data_length |
  //options/@Auto_increment |
  //options/@Index_length
' |
xmllint --format -
```

Basically it removes some values using xmlstarlet which I saw varied (even from consecutive dumps of the same database).  An XSLT style sheet could do the same job.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mysqldump xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <database name="mydb">
    <table_structure name="SomeTable">
      <field Field="foo" Type="int(12)" Null="NO" Key="PRI" Extra="" Comment=""/>
      <field Field="bar" Type="int(11)" Null="NO" Key="PRI" Extra="" Comment=""/>
      <field Field="baz" Type="int(11)" Null="NO" Key="PRI" Extra="" Comment=""/>
      <key Table="AccessControlList" Non_unique="0" Key_name="PRIMARY"
           Seq_in_index="1" Column_name="referenceID" Collation="A" Null=""
           Index_type="BTREE" Comment="" Index_comment=""/>
    <options Name="SomeTable" Engine="InnoDB" Version="10" Row_format="Compact"
           Max_data_length="0" Data_free="0" Create_time="2012-09-11 15:31:11"
           Collation="utf8_general_ci" Create_options="" Comment=""/>
[...]
```

(newlines between XML attributes were added for readability; they're not in the xmllint output)